# Separating client from server in Sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'd like to separate the entire client from my sails directory. Currently it looks like

```
- api
- assets (my client)
- config
- views
- all the other sails stuff
```

What I want

```
./server/
  - api
  - config
  - all the other sails stuff
./client/
  - all client related stuff
```

Is there any easy and fast way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's best to stick to a conventional app structure, you can customize this by configuring [`sails.config.paths`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/e83cc20c4f1383c2342fd6723567e6e4f82ffec9/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js#L32-L65) in your `.sailsrc` file.  For example:

```
"paths": {
  "config": "server/api/config",
  "controllers": "server/api/controllers",
  // etc.
}
```

For `assets/`, you'll need to make some changes in `tasks/pipeline.js`, and in the Grunt task config files in `tasks/config/*`.

> As to where you put `views/`, that's a really tough question that I went back and forth on many times over the year or so when I was initially working out the directory structure for the Sails boilerplate.  That's the reason it lives up at the top level.  I suppose if I had to categorize it within the scheme you're suggesting here, I would put it as "server/views/".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd like to have the frontend kinda exchangeable, hence the seperated client - that makes it easier.